# Why is my lambda function unable to access S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am creating AWS Lambda functions using the C++ SDK. I create these functions with the following role:

**Role Document:**

```
{
  "permissionsBoundary": {},
  "roleName": "my_role",
  "policies": [
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "AmazonS3FullAccess",
      "id": "SOMEID",
      "type": "managed",
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
    }
  ],
  "trustedEntities": [
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  ]
}
```

When it comes to permissions that's all I do. My lambda functions is still unable to access S3, though. Why is that?

Do I have to create a policy that lets the lambda function assume `my_role`?

Comment: Do your buckets have bucket policies with deny statements? Also to confirm you're using Lambda not Lambda@Edge?

Comment: Have you also validated from the console that policies are attached as expected?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams No. But when I check via the browser I can see that the `my_role` is attached. However the permissions are not listed

Comment: @ChrisWilliams About the S3 Bucket: All policies seem normal. All public access blocked. No other deny statements

Comment: Right so this will be the cause, do you have the full code of you attaching this? I can't see any examples in this format

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the cause? What code do you mean? A permission statement or the code used for creating the function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217686/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-user12547645).

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I was passing the wrong bucket name. The bucket name to an old account, which the function could (obviously) not access.